# How to pass string variable between two buttons

Tags: c#, variables, button

I have my button1_click, where I ask which button pressed you (this event has several buttons). Then I save the name in my string variable, but I need this variable in button2_click. How can i give my variable from button1_click to button2_click.

```
Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
String sName = clickedButton.Name.ToString();
```

Comment: Did you try to add on the derived class an instance field for that?

Comment: Provide code so it may be more explainable for us & easily understandable for you too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string name = "test";
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        name = "John Doe";
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(name);
    }
}
```

Try this.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this would help or if it is at all what you mean, but change the scope in which your variable is declared.
So instead of declaring your variable inside the scope of the on click event, just move it outside. This way you can access it globally within the current class/form.

You can read some more about this here.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/